# KeyError after build PySimpleGUI exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pysimplegui

I've trying to build exe for my PySimpleGui project. Problem is that when I start exe it give me error, but can't figure out why. Do I need to make some special magics when I use config.cfg file as my project folder root where project.py is?

```
File "project.py", line 46, in <module>

KeyError: 'CONF'
[21352] Failed to execute script 'project' due to unhandled exception!
```

My code related for line 46:

```
currentFile = __file__
realPath = os.path.realpath(currentFile)
dirPath = os.path.dirname(realPath)
dirName = os.path.basename(dirPath)

config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read(dirPath + '/config.cfg')


def get_config_section():
    if not hasattr(get_config_section, 'section_dict'):
        get_config_section.section_dict = collections.defaultdict()
        
        for section in config.sections():
            get_config_section.section_dict[section] = dict(config.items(section))
    
    return get_config_section.section_dict
  

config_dict = get_config_section()

# Values...

main_conf = config_dict['CONF']['key']
```

Comment: It maybe caused by file `config.cfg` not found, or no section `CONF` in `config.cfg` when your exe file executed.

Comment: Yeah I was print dirPath and config.cfg target path is /local/something.. So I need to figure out how to add correct path to that file. Code works fine before compiling it.

Comment: Perhaps try using `psgcompiler` as accessing the options for pyinstaller is made easier using it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the code before compiling it ?

Do you have the latest version of pyinstaller installed.

Try running the code and seeing the error

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah I have latest pyinstaller and it works before compiling it. Seems that dirPath variable is targeting  wrong path.